# What are some Axibase maintenance tips for creating more disk space

Tags: axibase

I am using Axibase Time Series Database Community Edition, version 11499 to collect stats on my application.  I am running out of space on its server.  What are the recommendations for creating more space?  Can I compress old data, or not store every sample of older data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by reviewing top inserts on `Admin: Receive Statistics` page. This page shows top-N metrics ranked by the number of inserts per hour/day.

[image: ATSD: Top Inserts]

Consider applying a retention interval for those metrics in the list which collect data that is not used or valuable after a certain period of time.

The retention interval can be modified for each metric separately on the Metric Settings page:

[image: Metric Settings]

Alternatively, use the Metrics tab to search and check multiple metrics to apply the same retention interval to the selected metrics:

[image: Metrics Multi Settings]

Keep in mind that you would need some extra disk space for the initial massive data pruning to work since it involves re-writing old files, so consider adding new retention settings gradually. It's a good idea to keep disk usage under 60%.

Comment: Hi Sergei. I hate to say it, but this sort of question isn't on topic for Stack Overflow. We deal with _programming_ questions. Simply using and configuring software isn't what we're about. If you're going to continue tagging posts with your software, there might need to be meta discussion about how on-topic your software is. This is in reference to a [suggested edit I reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20078492).